# Google Sheet: How to shift start of series in a chart with time axis?

Tags: google-sheets

I have data like:

| Date | Foo | Bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27/06/2022 | 12345.67 | 2345.67 |
| 04/07/2022 | 12354.76 | 2354.76 |
| 11/07/2022 | 12543.67 | 23456.78 |
| 18/07/2022 | 15432.76 | 26543.78 |

I had a chart with time axis (the one with the adjustable scale at the bottom) that used first column as X axis and second column as data, using first row as series titles.

However, now I'm in need to draw next series, but it has to start from 11/07/2022, no prior data drawn. Setting up the range as C4:C1000, starts drawing from the beginning (as on the image below). It occurred to me I need some sort of a filler for the data in the series to adjust, but I have no idea how to do it and I couldn't find any clue googling.

[image: The incorrect chart]

Hence question: how to shift start of series in a chart with time axis?

Comment: I am not sure if I understtod the issue correctly without seeing your spreadsheet, but if you want data that starts in a later cell than C4  -why do you not adjust the range accordingly (e.g. C20:C1000) - depending of which cell corresponds to your desired date?

Comment: Only one of multiple series. I've adjusted, but it takes first element as header and starts drawing from beginning as on the image above, not from the right date.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet (free of sensitive data)?